# How to pass value between two class in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a method1 in A class, the method1 finally it will result a ID,
I want to put this ID to method2 in B class.

How do I do this in Spring Boot?

Comment: share your code.

Comment: I would assume the exact same way you would do it before Spring Boot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply make the object of class A and use its method in class B.
You can also extend the class A.There are also many ways to do this.In Spring boot you have a controller class and some model class.Just like you use their methods you can use use class A's method in class B by either extending it or by making object of that class.